# Set the max length of multi-line textbox in InsertItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, textbox, maxlength

I'm trying to set the maxlength of a **multi-line** textbox. The snag I'm running into is I can't set it with javascript on page load because it is in an InsertItemTemplate. On page load it throws a javascript error (Error: Unable to set property 'maxLength' of undefined or null reference) until I go to add a record and the InsertItemTemplate shows up.

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function onPageLoad() {
            var txtAddNotes = document.getElementById("formViewNewItem_NotesTextBox");
            txtAddNotes.maxLength = 200;
         }
        </script>
        </head>
            <body onload="onPageLoad()">
       <asp:FormView ID="formViewNewItem" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
        DataSourceID="datasource1" OnDataBound="formViewNewItem_DataBound">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="NotesTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Width="350px" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
       </asp:FormView>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the formview `DefaultMode="Insert"`, then your script should be able to find the textbox on page load. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You can try calling your js function by checking for the current mode of the formview on page load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(formViewNewItem.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
        {
             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PageLoad", "onPageLoad();", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Bat_Programmer, thanks, I didn't know about the DefaultMode property. The only problem with this is that this formview is not supposed to show up until you click an "Add" button. With DefaultMode="Insert" it automatically is as if the "Add" button was clicked.